# multiline regex pattern in c++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I need the pattern to support multi-line. The pattern is taken from the users and they are able to include multi-line string as regex pattern.

For example:

```
std::regex re("^"+CWD+"("+path_delim+"[\\s\\S]*|$)");
if(std::regex_search(file,re)){
    //do something
}
```

The `CWD` variable can be a multi-line string.

P.S: It would be good if I can work this around with only `std::regex`, i.e I don't want to use any library if it's not lightweight. Also, it needs to be `c++11`.

Comment: When you say `CWD` is a *multiline string* what do you mean? It needs to be in regular expression syntax.

Comment: Do you want `^` and `$` to match the end of a *line* or the end of the string?

Comment: @Will end of the string.

Comment: @Galik ,good point, that means I will need to sanitize it too before passing it to the regex constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the multi line regex pattern is already supported. All I needed is to sanitize the variable before passing it to the regex constructor. This is the code I am using to sanitize the string to construct a valid regex:

```
String sanitizeRegexString(const String& s){
    std::regex re(R"([\s\S])");
    return std::regex_replace (s,re,"[$&]",std::regex_constants::format_default);
}
```

The above function takes a string and wraps all its characters around with `[]` thus the string is not interpreted as a regex pattern rather it is treated as a fixed string inside the pattern, while other strings concatenated with it (without sanitization) acts as regex pattern.